# How do I preload multiple images using Glide for later use

Tags: android, android-glide

I have many images that I want to preload and use later on. I want to make it so that I can load an image, hide it, and then load it again whenever I want.

https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Loading-and-Caching-on-Background-Threads#into
I have tried following this, but it doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
private void loadImage() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    FutureTarget<File> future = Glide.with(this)
            .load(R.drawable.image1)
            .downloadOnly(500, 500);
    File cacheFile = future.get();

    Bitmap myBitmap = Glide.with(this)
            .load(cacheFile)
            .asBitmap()
            .centerCrop()
            .into(500, 500)
            .get();
    Glide.with(this).load(myBitmap).into(image_name);
}
```

I tried using Picasso because I read that this can easily be done in it, but the images take really long to load in Picasso.

Comment: Why don't you just write it to a file and retrieve it anytime you want?

Comment: That would complicate things and add a lot of unnecessary code. I want a quick fix to the problem

Comment: ok, aren't you getting your image from the internet?

Comment: No, they are all in my drawable folder. I'm thinking that perhaps all I need is to just load the image, and then use clear() afterwards.